# Mute and UnMute in Objective-C on iOS

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

Hi guys ive been trying to find a way to mute and unmute (that is play audio) via Objective-C in-code, regardless of whether the app is in mute mode or not (physical mute toggled)

I see Instagram does that, where you can press the mute icon even if your phone is mute, and it will play video audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at [audio session categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW1)

With this code you can play audio when the Ring/Silent switch to silent.

```
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
            setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                  error: &setCategoryError];

if (!success) { /* handle the error in setCategoryError */ }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked a charm. But in terms of looking at category, it seems a bit hackish, but is there a way to do the opposite (enforce mute from mute)?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but if you want your app to obey the ring/silent switch use AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient or AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient. If you want to allow audio when the ring/silent switch is set to silent but have a UI element that allows the user to mute you could use AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback and set the volume to 0.

Comment: You set volume on the actual audio asset playing. For example, if you are using AVAudioPlayer to play an audio file, there's a volume property. Just set that to 0 to mute it and 1.0 for full volume.